# Adding Documentation of a library to manual pages

Tags: documentation, ffmpeg, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04, manpage

I am working with Ubuntu 12.04.1 . I am learning to make a basic video player using FFmpeg library in C . My manual pages don't show any entries for the headers/functions of the library . Can someone please show me a way to add the documentation to my manual pages .
It is much easy to search that way than searching on a web page everytime .

PS : I have tried to add documentation to man pages using Synaptic package manager . I installed a **ffmpeg-doc** package . But it doesn't seem to work .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

does this solve your problem -

http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Building-man-pages-td934441.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But I am not sure about the steps that I need to follow now . My environment is different and I installed all my libraries through Synaptic Package Manager , not from command line . Can you give me specific steps to only get the man pages for the FFmpeg library ?

Answer (score 1):

`FFmpeg` project use `doxygen` to create documentation. Doxygen can be configured to output man format.

Modify the file `doc/Doxyfile` like below, to tell doxygen you want man page format.

```
GENERATE_MAN           = YES
MAN_LINKS              = YES
```

`MAN_LINKS` option is very important, because if you omit it, you can not find the correct api call by name.

After you configure ffmpeg project by invoke `./configure ...`, use the target `apidoc` to create man pages.

```
$ make apidoc
```

The man pages will output to `doc/doxy/man/man3`, then append this path to your man page search path.

```
$ export MANPATH=$MANPATH:`pwd`/doc/doxy/man
```

Then you can look up man pages for ffmpeg library api.

```
$ man av_register_all
```

#### Note

The man pages generated by doxygen for most of the api library call just a link to real source man page.

After open with man, you have to use key `/` to search and jump to documentation part you want.