# Linux: The man pages about ffmpeg library

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, manpage

Just as titile. I want to install man pages about ffmpeg library on linux. when type man "av_register_all", show me the description just as "man printf".

I know i should put the pages to /usr/local/man. but where is the pages about ffmpeg library

Comment: Maybe duplicated with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088271/adding-documentation-of-a-library-to-manual-pages).

Comment: Year, the question looks same. but answer is about "man ffmpeg", not the library function, like "man av_register_all".

Comment: See the updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088271/adding-documentation-of-a-library-to-manual-pages/44845332#44845332).